# Dynamically named gt plots based on color palettes selected using R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, purrr, gt

With sample data and code below, I'm able to dynamically draw `gt()` plots for each element of list of dataframes, and I set color for `error` column:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("M0000607", "M0000609", "M0000612"), `2021-08(actual)` = c(12.6, 
19.2, 8.3), `2021-09(actual)` = c(10.3, 17.3, 6.4), `2021-10(actual)` = c(8.9, 
15.7, 5.3), `2021-11(actual)` = c(7.3, 14.8, 3.1), `2021-12(actual)` = c(6.1, 
14.2, 3.5), `2021-08(pred)` = c(11.65443222, 14.31674997, 7.084180415
), `2021-09(pred)` = c(12.29810914, 17.7143733, 6.057927385), 
    `2021-10(pred)` = c(9.619846116, 15.54553601, 6.525992602
    ), `2021-11(pred)` = c(8.352097939, 13.97318204, 3.164682627
    ), `2021-12(pred)` = c(6.113631596, 14.16243166, 3.288372517
    ), `2021-08(error)` = c(2.082307066, 1.146759554, 0.687406723
    ), `2021-09(error)` = c(1.631350383, 2.753457736, 2.952737781
    ), `2021-10(error)` = c(0.945567783, 4.883250027, 1.215819585
    ), `2021-11(error)` = c(1.998109138, 0.414373304, 0.342072615
    ), `2021-12(error)` = c(0.719846116, 0.154463985, 1.225992602
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

year_months <- c('2021-12', '2021-11', '2021-10')  
curr <- lubridate::ym(year_months)
prev <- curr - months(2L)
dfs <- mapply(function(x, y) {
  df[c(
    "id", 
    format(seq.Date(y, x, by = "month"), "%Y-%m(actual)"), 
    format(x, "%Y-%m(pred)"), 
    format(x, "%Y-%m(error)")
  )]
}, curr, prev, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

plotGT <- function(data){
  plot <- data %>% 
    gt() %>% 
    data_color(
      columns = 6, # set color for error column
      colors = scales::col_numeric(
        palette =
          c("blue", "green", "orange", "red"),  # named with color 1
          # c('#feb8cd', '#ffffff', '#69cfd5'), # named with color 2
        domain = c(0, 10)
      )
    )
  print(plot)
  # gtsave(plot, file = file.path(glue("./plot_color1.png")))
  
}

mapply(plotGT, dfs)
```

Result for colors `c("blue", "green", "orange", "red")`:

[image]

Result for colors `c('#feb8cd', '#ffffff', '#69cfd5')`:

[image]

In order to go further, I hope to save the outputs based if conditions: if I choose the first color palette, I will name the plot by i.e., `plot_color1.png`, for the second, named by `plot_color2.png`, but I wish to run the whole code once, save all two figures one time.

So my question is how could I modify the code above to achieve that? Thanks for your help at advance.

Maybe some code like: `gtsave(plot, file = file.path(glue("./plot_color{i}.png")))` based on if-else conditions, but I don't know how to do that exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to make use of a named `list` of color palettes like so, which would also make it easier to switch between different palettes:

**EDIT**

- I fixed a bug. I used a `<-` inside the `pals` list instead of `=` which was the reason for the error you got.
- To loop over the palettes I added `pal_choice` as an argument to your table function. Doing so we can loop over `pals` using e.g. lapply.
- Additionally, as you are looping over multiple `dfs` I added a name argument and added names to your list of data frames. As is the tables were exported under the same filename so actually you ended up with one file containing the last table.
- I also uncommented the `print` for the reprex.

```r
library(gt)

pal_choice <- "color2"
pals <- list(color1 = c("blue", "green", "orange", "red"), 
             color2 = c('#feb8cd', '#ffffff', '#69cfd5'))


plotGT <- function(data, name, pal_choice){
  plot <- data %>% 
    gt() %>% 
    data_color(
      columns = 6, # set color for error column
      colors = scales::col_numeric(
        palette = pals[[pal_choice]],
        domain = c(0, 10)
      )
    )
  #print(plot)
  gtsave(plot, file = glue::glue("./plot_{name}_{pal_choice}.png"))
}

names(dfs) <- letters[seq_along(dfs)]

lapply(names(pals), function(x) {
  mapply(plotGT, dfs, names(dfs), MoreArgs = list(pal_choice = x))  
})
#> [[1]]
#>                                                                                                                     a 
#> "/private/var/folders/l7/hltv70p95zqfdq9z09h8m9bw0000gn/T/Rtmp9LLLHO/reprex-2b71746b0fd-petit-dore/plot_a_color1.png" 
#>                                                                                                                     b 
#> "/private/var/folders/l7/hltv70p95zqfdq9z09h8m9bw0000gn/T/Rtmp9LLLHO/reprex-2b71746b0fd-petit-dore/plot_b_color1.png" 
#>                                                                                                                     c 
#> "/private/var/folders/l7/hltv70p95zqfdq9z09h8m9bw0000gn/T/Rtmp9LLLHO/reprex-2b71746b0fd-petit-dore/plot_c_color1.png" 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>                                                                                                                     a 
#> "/private/var/folders/l7/hltv70p95zqfdq9z09h8m9bw0000gn/T/Rtmp9LLLHO/reprex-2b71746b0fd-petit-dore/plot_a_color2.png" 
#>                                                                                                                     b 
#> "/private/var/folders/l7/hltv70p95zqfdq9z09h8m9bw0000gn/T/Rtmp9LLLHO/reprex-2b71746b0fd-petit-dore/plot_b_color2.png" 
#>                                                                                                                     c 
#> "/private/var/folders/l7/hltv70p95zqfdq9z09h8m9bw0000gn/T/Rtmp9LLLHO/reprex-2b71746b0fd-petit-dore/plot_c_color2.png"
```

Comment: Thanks, does your solution save `plot_color2.png` as well? I tested, it seems only save plots with color1.

Comment: I understand, I need to set `pal_choice <- "color2"`, to save plots for color2, right?

Comment: Hej @ahbon. Yep. Right. That was my idea: Setting the color palette as an option or parameter at the beginning of the script or Rmd which is then added as part of the filename.

Comment: Hello @stefan, sorry for this late to post new testing result, I found when I select `pal_choice <- "color2"` and rerun the code, it will raise an error: `Error in UseMethod("toPaletteFunc") : no applicable method for 'toPaletteFunc' applied to an object of class "NULL" Called from: toPaletteFunc(pal, alpha = alpha, nlevels = nlevels)`. Any ideas to fix this issue?

Comment: BTW, how could we convert your code to for loop for iterating each element of list of color palette?

Comment: Hi @ahbon. I just made an edit to fix the error which was due to a typo. I also adjusted the code so that you could loop over all color palettes.